# within a pandas DF, I need to determine the max value of a list of columns in each row

Tags: pandas, dataframe, max

I have a pandas Dataframe with I columns and J rows.  I need the max value for each row from a subset of columns.  For example, assume I have columns "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" and "F".  I need the max value of (C,D,E) for each row.  I'll store that value in a new column "G".

Can Someone please explain this?  Thank you!!!

John Deatherage

"

Comment: Please provide a sample DF with the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a dataframe `df` with columns A-F as you described, you can store the max of C,D,E for each row in column G as follows:

```
df['G'] = df[['C','D','E']].max(axis=1)
```

`df[['C','D','E']]` returns a subset of your dataframe that only includes columns C,D,E. Calling `max` on this with `axis=1` tells it to compute a "row-wise" max across the columns on this dataframe, meaning the max of C,D and E for each row. If you set `axis=0` it would compute the "column-wise" max across the rows, which would instead give you the max of column C, the max of column D and the max of column E across all rows.